# Pixel and Tonic Playa direction

Tags: playa

I am a channel called products

I need to relate a product to other products

I edit the product say PRODUCT 1 and assign 5 other products to be related to that product
PRODUCT 2
PRODUCT 3
PRODUCT 4
PRODUCT 5
PRODUCT 6

Is it possible that when I go to edit one of the related products PRODUCT 2 that its know its related to PRODUCT 1 and it will be displayed/selected in the playa field automatically?

Thanks

Comment: It sounds to me like you need a higher level of abstraction - possibly categories. Would it make sense to categorise your products into groups?

Comment: Its fine I think we can manage with the standard multi select field in the publish section. Regarding categories I dont think this will work as we are relating products to a products similar to upsell, cross sell, related products on an e-commerce site

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing is reverse relationships. Playa has no such field for the publish page, but it is possible to get the reverse relationship in the templates with the {exp:playa:parents} tag.